# Changing upload_max_filesize on a shared webhost? (Apache, PHP)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ini-set

I want to change upload_max_filesize on my shared webhosting account to something greater than 2M.

Since I don't have access to php.ini, and apparently you can't use ini_set to change upload_max_filesize, I don't know what to do. Maybe something involving .htaccess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hosts let you do a custom compile of php yourself, some let you request changes to php.ini if you contact support, some don't let you do anything.

If your hosting company refuses to let you modify your php setup in any way, I'd consider other hosting companies personally...

Comment: I would agree. If you need this level of control for your scripts and the company isn't helpful, you might need to go elsewhere. Kinda like growing up :). If you call you can at least find out if they will allow it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you contacted the hosting company? They may be willing to change the size and/or they might be able to tell you if you are able too. They might have disabled .htaccess and ini_set() for the max_file_size configuration setting and in such case it doesn't matter what you do, it is ignored.